# how to use django-valuate?

Tags: django

I am using a system of punctuation, [this site](https://github.com/micrypt/django-valuate), I'm just using the example that comes, I have not created any app just use the example,  I've done syncdb, add in the admin.

LikeDislike

- Like 1
- Dislike 0

I have also added records to the model post, but when I go to 127.0.0.1:8000 I have the next error:

> DoesNotExist at / ValuationType matching query does not exist. Request
>   Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Django Version: 1.3.1
>   Exception Type: DoesNotExist Exception Value: ValuationType matching
>   query does not exist. Exception Location: C: \ Python27 \ lib \
>   site-packages \ django \ db \ models \ query.py in get, line 349
>   Python Executable: C: \ Python27 \ python.exe Python Version: 2.7.2
>   Python Path: ['D: \ \ Django \ \ AppFabric \ \ vote \ \ sample',   'C:
>   \ \ Python27 \ \ lib \ \ site-packages \ \
>   django_pure_pagination-0.1-py2.7.egg',   'C: \ \ Python27 \ \ lib \ \
>   site-packages \ \ django_uni_form-0.9.0-py2.7.egg',   'C: \ \ Python27
>   \ \ lib \ \ site-packages \ \
>   django_email_confirmation-0.2-py2.7.egg',   'C: \ \ Python27 \ \ lib \
>   \ site-packages \ \ python_openid-2.2.5-py2.7.egg',   'C: \ \ Python27
>   \ \ lib \ \ site-packages \ \ oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg',   'C: \ \
>   Python27 \ \ lib \ \ site-packages \ \ httplib2-0.7.2-py2.7.egg',
>   'C: \ \ Python27 \ \ lib \ \ site-packages \ \ 0.8.0rc2-py2.7.egg
>   mock-',   'C: \ \ Python27 \ \ lib \ \ site-packages \ \ pip-1.0.2,
>   py2.7.egg'   'C: \ \ Python27 \ \ lib \ \ site-packages \ \
>   django_socialauth-0.1.2c-py2.7.egg',   'C: \ \ Python27 \ \ lib \ \
>   site-packages \ \ oauth-1.0.1-py2.7.egg',   'C: \ \ Python27 \ \ lib \
>   \ site-packages \ \ django_socialregistration-0.5-py2.7.egg',   'C: \
>   \ Python27 \ \ lib \ \ site-packages \ \
>   django_disqus-0.4.1-py2.7.egg',   'C: \ \ Python27 \ \ lib \ \
>   site-packages \ \ django_threadedcomments-0.9-py2.7.egg',   'C: \ \
>   Python27 \ \ lib \ \ site-packages \ \
>   django_valuate-1.0_beta_2.2-py2.7.egg',   'C: \ \ Windows \ \ system32
>   \ \ python27.zip'   'C: \ \ Python27 \ \ DLLs',   'C: \ \ Python27 \ \
>   lib',   'C: \ \ Python27 \ \ lib \ \ plat-win'   'C: \ \ Python27 \ \
>   lib \ \ lib-tk',   'C: \ \ Python27',   'C: \ \ Python27 \ \ lib \ \
>   site-packages',   'C: \ \ Python27 \ \ lib \ \ site-packages \ \ PIL' 
>   '../',   '../']

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to go to http://localhost:8000/admin and create a ValuationType with a slug named `like-dislike` and your error will go away.  If you want to mess around with the main app you will also need to create a couple posts.

Other things to note is if you have created/deleted stuff you wil get into a bad state because they use pk=1 to start over just delete db.sqlite.

Good luck.

Comment: the problem is in template home.html in lines 7,9,11 because it must be the name you put into your ValuateType , Tanks